Override style of children elements of one component again using StyledComponents when using them in another component
I have a Component like
const CalendarComponent: React.FC = () => (
  <DropdownContainer>
    <CustomDropdown>
      <span>{label}</span>
      <ArrowIconContainer>
        <NextImage src={DownArrowIcon} />
      </ArrowIconContainer>
    </CustomDropdown>
    {isOpen && <CalendarComponent />}
  </DropdownContainer>
);

These all elements (DropdownContainer,CustomDropdown,ArrowIconContainer,CalendarComponent) are defined using StyledComponents in another file.
Now, I am using this component CalendarComponent in another component, from that component I want to override the styles of these inner elements (DropdownContainer,CustomDropdown,ArrowIconContainer,CalendarComponent) using StyledComponents.
Is this possible ? And What is the best practice to achieve this kind of scenario. It will be better if someone can explain with example as I am new to this.
I tried something as below:
const CalendarDateDropDown = styled(DropdownCalendarComponent)`
  & > div {
    display: flex;
    width: 199px !important;
    padding: 4px 16px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: stretch;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: var(--Input-Field-Backround, #f5f5f7);
  }
`;

but its not working, I want the best practice that is followed in react community to achieve this.

Please don't ask for best practice. What's best practice is different for each team and use-case. If you want to override styles as you are, you need to pass the className prop in CalendarComponent to DropdownContainer otherwise the styles will not apply.

got it. I tried that and it works, no apart from DropdownContainer I have 3-4 different elements as well, should I pass className for each of them or is there a different and better approach.

You should only need to pass the classname to the parent component. But you will need to make sure that your selectors are correct

I passed the className to CalendarComponent and appended it with DropdownContainer like
, this is applied, now I have another styled component defined inside  which is  how to pass css to this ?

You don't need to. As long as DropdownContainer and CustomDropdown are styled component you can import them into CalendarDateDropDown and select them directly

The correct way as explained by @evolutionxbox in comments is to pass className as parameter to the container inside the child component. Then pass your custom class from parent component. Example:
//child component

const CalendarComponent: React.FC<CalendarComponentProps> = ({
  className}) => (
  <DropdownContainer className={className}>
    <CustomDropdown>
      <span>{label}</span>
      <ArrowIconContainer>
        <NextImage src={DownArrowIcon} />
      </ArrowIconContainer>
    </CustomDropdown>
    {isOpen && <CalendarComponent />}
  </DropdownContainer>
);

//Below section will be in parent component or in a separate styled file. Its not part of child component.

export const CalendarDate = styled(CalendarComponent)`
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: stretch;
  border-radius: 8px;
  span {
    color: var(--Slate-Gray, var(--Grey-text, #89909f));
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
  }`;

In this way, the custom style will be applied to DropdownContainer of calendarComponent and also on span under DropDownContainer.
Then you can used the CalendarDate in your parent component.
